# Setting the maxitems in the inline TCA field without hiding the add button BUG?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I am trying to use the Inline form in the TCA in Typo3 10.

The problem that I am faced right now:
The add button would disappear when the max allowed field are reached and id i delete the last element the button **will not appear again**. ONLY IF I ADD THIS ELEMENT **IN THE PAGE CONFIGURATION**, if I make it inside content element would work perfectly.

```
  //---- Only One Data
        'tx_data' => [
            'label' => 'test',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'allowed' => 'tx_media',
                'appearance' => [
                    'enabledControls' => [
                        'delete'    => false,
                        'dragdrop'  => false,
                        'hide'      => true,
                        'info'      => true,
                        'new'       => true,
                        'sort'      => false,
                        'localize'  => true,
                    ],
                    'collapseAll'   => false,
                    'expandSingle'  => false,
                    'useSortable'   => false,
                ],
                'behaviour' => [
                    'allowLanguageSynchronization'          => true,
                    'localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization'  => true,
                    'enableCascadingDelete'                 => true,
                    'disableMovingChildrenWithParent'       => false,
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_media',
                'foreign_field' => 'parent',
                'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
                'minitems' => 1,
                'maxitems' => 1,

            ],
        ],
```

Did anyone know how to fix it ?
Thanks.
[image: The button][image: there is no button if I delete the previous element here]

I have already put  enabledControls -> new -> true.

https://giphy.com/gifs/eepDm42xfyTA6sZfxU

Comment: I don't get your point. That behaviour is intended. What's the use for this button for an editor, when the maxitems value is reached? When you an item, the button will appear again.

Comment: @PeterKraume exactly the button doesn't appear again.

Comment: That's mean if delete the item that I have added, the button will not also appear.

Comment: I've just tested it with one of my extensions: with `minitems => 1` and `maxitems => 1` the button is only visible when there is no item. If there is an item, you need to delete it and than the button appears again.

Comment: What !! so my TCA configuration it's right maybe the problem is with my sql file ? could you please your sql test code ? I am trying to save a GIF on my screen so that you can see that the button will not appear again.

Comment: @PeterKraume this a GIF : Could you please check it : https://giphy.com/gifs/eepDm42xfyTA6sZfxU

Comment: @PeterKraume I just try the code inside Content element and it's working fine BUT it's not working if i put this element in page configuration (PAGE Table) will not work

Comment: Can confirm the behavior.
Seems, the deletion of the inline record is not stored immediately. Otherwise, it can't be stored with min/max=1 because it would be empty for a little moment. With maxitems=2 you can follow up the wanted behavior.

Comment: @JulianHofmann is this a BUG ? With maxitems=2 it's not excatly what i want. I want to limit the user of an Item.

Comment: Sure, maximum = 2 is not the same but shows the expected behavior when maxitems are reached or when the maximum possible value is deleted. In my opinion here is a bug for maxitems = 1